# Is there a way to output all the cross validation models results in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cross-validation

I am using cross validation for model and parameter selection in Spark. because of application need, I am not only need to know the best model, but the results for all models. 
When I worked with python sklearn, I can use

```
clf = GridSearchCV()
clf.cv_results_
```

to print out all the models, which is something as following:
Grid scores on development set:

```
0.986 (+/-0.016) for {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.959 (+/-0.029) for {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.988 (+/-0.017) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.982 (+/-0.026) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.988 (+/-0.017) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.982 (+/-0.025) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.988 (+/-0.017) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.982 (+/-0.025) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.975 (+/-0.014) for {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}
0.975 (+/-0.014) for {'C': 10, 'kernel': 'linear'}
0.975 (+/-0.014) for {'C': 100, 'kernel': 'linear'}
0.975 (+/-0.014) for {'C': 1000, 'kernel': 'linear'}
```

In spark I have

```
val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(pipeline)
  .setEvaluator(new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramLRGrid)
  .setNumFolds(3)
val cvModel = cv.fit(trainingData)
```

I am wondering if there is a similar way as clf.cv_results_ in spark that I can see all the models

Answer (score 0):

this should help:

```
cvModel.subModels
```

as described here:
[Spark CrossValidatorModel access other models than the bestModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874546/spark-crossvalidatormodel-access-other-models-than-the-bestmodel)