# Pyspark k-fold cross validation average RMSE

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

I am running linear regression with a k-fold cross validation on a dataset using Pyspark.  I am at the moment only able to determine the RMSE of the best model. But I want the average RMSE for all the models evaluated in the cross validation. How do I get the average RMSE for all evaluated models in the cross validation?

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder

file_name = '/tmp/user/userfile/LS.csv'
data = spark.read.options(header='true', inferschema='true',                            
                          delimiter=',').csv(file_name)
data.cache()
features = ["x"]
lr_data = data.select(col("y").alias("label"), *features)
(training, test) = lr_data.randomSplit([.7, .3])

vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=features, outputCol="features")
training_ds = vectorAssembler.transform(training)
test_ds = vectorAssembler.transform(test)

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=5, solver="l-bfgs") # solver="l-bfgs" here

modelEvaluator=RegressionEvaluator()

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1,0.01]) 
                              .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0, 1]).build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=modelEvaluator,
                          numFolds=2)

cvModel = crossval.fit(training_ds)

prediction = cvModel.transform(test_ds)

evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="label",
                                predictionCol="prediction",
                                metricName="rmse")

rms = evaluator.evaluate(prediction)
print("Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) on test data = %g" % rms)
```

Comment: I edited your tags. Please check what tags you're using. (ML is a family of programming languages.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply need to extract other models from crossvalidator

[Spark CrossValidatorModel access other models than the bestModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874546/spark-crossvalidatormodel-access-other-models-than-the-bestmodel)

Then proceed with RegressionEvaluator on each and count average by hand.