# How can I access computed metrics for each fold in a CrossValidatorModel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

How can I get the computed metrics for each fold from a `CrossValidatorModel` in `spark.ml`? I know I can get the average metrics using `model.avgMetrics` but is it possible to get the raw results on each fold to look at eg. the variance of the results?

I am using Spark 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Studying the [spark code here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/CrossValidator.scala)

For the folds, you can do the iteration yourself like this:

```
    val splits = MLUtils.kFold(dataset.toDF.rdd, $(numFolds), $(seed))
    //K-folding operation starting
    //for each fold you have multiple models created cfm. the paramgrid
    splits.zipWithIndex.foreach { case ((training, validation), splitIndex) =>
      val trainingDataset = sparkSession.createDataFrame(training, schema).cache()
      val validationDataset = sparkSession.createDataFrame(validation, schema).cache()


      val models = est.fit(trainingDataset, epm).asInstanceOf[Seq[Model[_]]]
      trainingDataset.unpersist()
      var i = 0
      while (i < numModels) {
        val metric = eval.evaluate(models(i).transform(validationDataset, epm(i)))
        logDebug(s"Got metric $metric for model trained with ${epm(i)}.")
        metrics(i) += metric
        i += 1
      }
```

This is in scala, but the ideas are very clearly outlined.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874546/spark-crossvalidatormodel-access-other-models-than-the-bestmodel) that outlines results per fold. Hope this helps.